# upgrade app on jailbreak device

Tags: iphone

I have a free app. I also make the version for jailbreak iphones.
The problem is that the normal upgrade on iphone is just run updating of appstore app.
But for the version works on jailbreak device, I hope I can check whether the new version existes,
if sure, it downloads the version from web and installs it on the device automatically.

What kind of sdk I need to call for install the ipa file on jailbreak devices?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even on jailbroken devices, an app cannot be updated automatically; the user must take part in beginning the process of updating (the usual way being when the user presses "Update" in the App store). Although you can't automatically update your app, be it on jailbroken or non-jailbroken devices, there is a library called iVersion by Nick Lockwood the reminds the user when an update to your app is available. You can download iVersion at its [Github page](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion). Also on the Github page is comprehensive installation and configuration instructions, so I recommend that you check it out.

Hope this helps!